# Android: Call setOnTouchListener inside switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener

Tags: java, android

I'm switching between two images and I want to setOnTouchListener when only 1 of the images is displayed. Here is the code:

```
        Switch switch2 = (Switch) rootView.findViewById(R.id.switch2);
        final ImageView iv = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image2);
        switch2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sijuki2);
                } else {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sijuki2_default);
                }
            }
        });

        if (switch2.equals(false)) {
            if (iv != null) {
                iv.setOnTouchListener(this);
            }
        }
```

But OnTouch is not working in the app. I tried putting `iv.setOnTouchListener(this)` inside `onCheckedChanged` but I got an error on `(this)`.

Thanks.

Comment: what is your setOnTouchListener supposed to do?

Comment: I have a FrameLayout with an image (of a comic book page) with another image on top set to invisible. When the user touches the screen, it gets the pixel they touched and checks the color of the pixel on the invisible image. It plays sounds depending on the color of the pixel. It's a good way to turn comic books text and speech bubbles into buttons

Comment: is your switch's check change listener working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the functionality I wanted. Thanks Usman for your help. This is what I ended up doing.

```
        Switch switch2 = (Switch) rootView.findViewById(R.id.switch2);
        final ImageView iv = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image2);
        switch2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sijuki2);
                    iv.setOnTouchListener(null);
                } else {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.sijuki2_default);
                    iv.setOnTouchListener(SecondFragment.this);
                }
            }
        });

        if (iv != null) {
            iv.setOnTouchListener(this);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**To use OnTouchListener, you have to implement view.OnTouchListenerin your fragment like that,**

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener{
```

When you implement view.OnTouchListener, Then Inside Your Fragment you have to override onTouchmethod.

**Your onTouchMethod should look like this,**

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if(view.getId()==R.id.iv)
  //your code here
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Usman. So in ```If (switch2.equals(false)) {```? or in onCheckedChanged?

Comment: in      if (switch2.equals(false)) {

Comment: it doesn't work. error. setOnTouchListener(android.view.View.OnTouchListener) in View cannot be applied to (androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity)

Comment: but when i use ```iv.setOnTouchListener(SecondFragment.this);``` it runs but the functionality doesn't work

Comment: Updated answer Again

Comment: Thanks for your help but I did it a different way in the end.